# Determinar a posição onde ocorre maior subida de valor num array

Tags: c

Boas estou fazendo o seguinte exercício em linguagem C
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu fiz o seguinte código e não entendo porque não está a resultar...

```
int maior_subida(int *tab, int dim) {
int i, pos=0, diferenca=0, diferenca_anterior=0;
for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    diferenca = ((*(tab+i+1))-(*(tab+i)));
    if (diferenca > diferenca_anterior){
        pos = (i + 1);
        diferenca_anterior=diferenca;
    }
}
return pos;}

int main(){
int tabela[10]={31,3309,43,5,25461,10,9,7,537,1}, posicao;
posicao=maior_subida(tabela,10);
printf("O elemento que tem maior diferenca do anterior e o que esta na posicao: %d\n",posicao);}
```

Com este código obtenho o seguinte resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem algumas falhas em seu código, por exemplo:

1. a diferenca já poderia ser inicializada como diferenca = tab[1] - tab[0] e pos = 1;
2. outra coisa é o uso do *(tab+i), em C vetores são ponteiros, tanto é que você pode definir coisas como char *string = "Olá", vá sempre pelo mais fácil de visualizar, nesse caso seria o tab[i];
3. outro erro é o fato do seu for ir de 0 à < dim, no caso de ser dim == 10, seu for iria de 0 à 9, porém quando i fosse 9 e tentasse fazer *(tab+i+1) resultaria em tab+10, que causaria bufferOverflow e poderia causar a parada repentina do seu programa;
4. e outra coisa que poderia ser melhorada seria a eliminação da variável diferenca_anterior, como seu retorno deve ser da posição em que ocorre o descrito na questão, logo é desnecessário guardar a diferença em cada execução do loop.

Aqui deixo o seu código com as mudanças que citei, observe as mudanças e aplique as dicas em próximos problemas:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int maior_subida(int *tab, int dim) {
   int pos=1, diferenca;
   diferenca = tab[1] - tab[0];
   for (int i = 1; i < dim-1; i++) {
      if (diferenca < (tab[i+1] - tab[i]) ){
         diferenca = tab[i+1] - tab[i];
         pos = i+1;
      }
   }
   return pos;
}

int main(){
   int tabela[10]={31,3309,43,5,25461,10,9,7,537,1}, posicao = 0;
   posicao = maior_subida(tabela,10);
   printf("O elemento que tem maior diferenca do anterior e o que esta na posicao: %d\n",posicao);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, realmente não reparado na possibilidade do bufferOverflow, ja corrigi o meu algoritmo e o programa funciona correctamente. Em relação ao que disse no ponto 2, eu ando a aprender a manipular ponteiros por isso a escolha de usar *tab em vez de tab[0]